# Error while building l2fwd in DPDK

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to build the module l2fwd in DPDK and I keep getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYXQG.png). I am using an Oracle Virtual Box with Ubuntu 16.04 OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

l2fwd example application fails with the following message:

```
WARNING: Master core has no memory on local socket!
error allocating rte services array
```

Looks like you missed the step with huge page setup. Basically, you need to allocate huge pages for the application with the following command:

```
# echo 512 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
```

Please find more details in [DPDK Getting Started Guide](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/linux_gsg/sys_reqs.html#use-of-hugepages-in-the-linux-environment).